# date time countdown module?

Tags: datetime

trying to create a groupon-deal style 'time left to buy' field, a dynamic countdown field.

[image]

Any modules can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://drupal.org/project/countdown module does this on a block level, but since all the 'heavy lifting' is done on the client side with javascript, I wouldn't imagine it would be all that difficult to rejigger it to look at an appropriately css'ed field...